# Plotting inverse laplace function in matlab

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm currently working on an assignment where we want to plot an output function.

Since our input signal( v(t) )is in the Time domain and our transfer function ( H(s) ) is in the S domain.
we want to bring our input signal to the S domain so we can simply use multiplication and then bring it back to the time domain to plot.

The error I'm getting is:
Error using plot
Data must be numeric, datetime, duration or an array convertible to double.

````
syms s C R L T n

C = (36)*10^(-6); % Our given values for capacitance, inductance and resistance
L = 0.18;
R = 100;
T = 1/50; % Period
H = 1/(C*R*s + C*L*s^2 + 1);        %Transfer function
y = 3/2;                           %c_0

for n = -5:1:5
    c_k = (((-1)^n)/(pi*(2*n+1)))*exp(1i*(2*n+1)*100*pi*t);
    y = y + c_k;
end
V = laplace(y);
Vc = V * H;
vc = ilaplace(Vc);

vpa(vc);
plot(t,vc);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I see different issues in this RLC filter circuit.

Here are the modifications you should operate at the end of your program:

```
vc = real(ilaplace(Vc));%"real" is compulsory even if... it is already real (very small imaginary parts way cree on) 
vvc = string(vc);
close all;hold on;axis([-1,1,-3,3]);
f=str2func(['@(t)(',vvc,')']);%in order to get a function
for t=-1:0.1:1
    plot(t,f(t),'.')
end;
```

1. You have to change types : "syms" type has to be converted into "string" type
2. You have to convert to real.
3. "t" is symbolic: Matlab cannot use it as it is; you know that you must give to $t$ a range of values, for example $t=-1:0.1:1$.
4. We use here the so-called "immediate definition" of a function (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)
5. What is this function $y$ ? It looks like a truncated Fourier series expansion of a ramp function ?
6. vpa(...) isn't useful. Instead of for example $2/3$, it gives you $0.66666666666666666666666666...$ with thirty decimals... It's better to keep the fractional form.
7. The value of T isn't used.

Comment: I have completely modified my answer. Any comment ?